# Density-Density correlation function - Bose Hubbard in Bogoliubov theory

Tags: correlation-functions

a Bose-Hubbard-Hamiltonian in the Bogoliubov theory can be written as (http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0011108v1.pdf):

$H=\sum_k \omega_k b_k^\dagger b_k$

I tried now to calculate the density-density correlation function in the Bogoliubov approximation.

$<\rho(j*a)\rho(0)>$,

where j is an integer number and a the lattice constant. The gas shall be in a thermal state. What would you except? Assuming a lattice with 1000 sites and periodic boundary conditions. I thought the correlation would drop exponentially from one to zero, but my result is that it drops not to zero, but something between 0 and 1.

[image: density]

Anyone any explanation?:-)

Comment: I would expect the correlation function to factorise at large distances, thus tending to $\langle \rho(r)\rangle^2$. Without knowing what the mean density is it's hard to see if this is happening in your data. A better correlation measure is the normalised pair correlation function
$$ g^{(2)}(r) = \frac{\langle \rho(r)\rho(0) \rangle - \langle \rho(r)\rangle^2 }{\langle \rho(r)\rangle^2}.$$
This vanishes for uncorrelated lattice sites, i.e. for sufficiently large $r$.